# How to generate unique object id in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

When I use Mongodb with Java, I want to generate Object id at clients. Before I insert a record, however, I have to query mongodb first to make sure that the id generated by ObjectId() method is unique. Is there any way that I can generate unique object id without accessing mongodb twice?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Object IDs are not like sequential ids you use in a RDMS. If they are properly generated according to the [Object ID specification](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification) you will not need to worry about them being unique.

All you have to do is ensure you always create a new Object ID rather than reusing them.

Comment: So if I generate id by: ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
then the id must be unique already? Thank you

Comment: @vienna Correct. You just have to make sure to call it every time you save a record to the database.

Answer (score 70):

You can generate ObjectId on the client without consulting database. Such ID will be unique (you'll have to try damn hard to get two identical object ids).

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId();

// or this
ObjectId id = ObjectId.get();
```

Comment: No difference. ObjectId#get just calls the constructor.

Comment: @Jennifer: this is java, not javascript.

Comment: In a highly concurrent setup with dockered processes (same PID), this procedure might be dangerous, leading the ID collisions. Very unlikely and the call to "NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()" would have to fail, resulting in a randomized machiene part of the ID. But you can't be sure enough, right?

Comment: @AndréB. Huh, what do you mean, the same pid? (I have no idea about docker :) )

Comment: In a docker container, PIDs start with zero, try running "docker run ubuntu ps ax".

Answer (score 13):

As of MongoDB Java Driver 3.3.0, there are the following ways to create ObjectIds.

**Using the constructor without parameters:** *Provides unique ObjectId*

```
1. ObjectId id1 = new ObjectId(); //Generates unique id 

    1.1. ObjectId id2 = ObjectId.get(); //Calls new ObjectId();
```

**Using the parameterized constructors:** *Parameters influence the uniqueness of the ObjectId*

```
2. public ObjectId(byte[] bytes) // Receives a byte array of size 12.

3. public ObjectId(String hexString) //Receives a String that is a hexadecimal representation of 12 bytes.

4. public ObjectId(Date date) // Receives a Date object

5. public ObjectId(Date date, int counter) //Receives date and a counter

6. public ObjectId(Date date,
            int machineIdentifier,
            short processIdentifier,
            int counter) //Receives Date, MachineId, PID and counter.

7. public ObjectId(int timestamp,
            int machineIdentifier,
            short processIdentifier,
            int counter) //Receives Epoch time in sec, MachineId, PID and counter.
```

**Understanding ObjectId:**

ObjectId consists of 12 bytes, divided as follows:

```
               ObjectID layout

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11

|time          |machine    |pid    |inc      |
```

Comment: This is no longer the structure. According do the current impl docs here (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification) the format of the 12 bytes are 4 bytes: time, 5 bytes: random, 3 bytes: counter