# Can mongo document ID format be customised?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to encode some meaning behinds first N characters of every document ID i.e. make first three characters determine a document type sensible to the system being used in.

Comment: You can easily generate your own ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a custom _id when you insert the document. If the document to be inserted doesn't contain _id, then MongoDB will insert a ObejctId for you.

The _id can be of any type but keeping it uniform for all the documents makes sense if you are accessing from application layer.

You can refer one of the old questions at SO - [How to generate unique object id in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723229/how-to-generate-unique-object-id-in-mongodb)