# Mongo Async Java driver doesnt return the id in insertOne method

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am struggling to fix this problem where I have to get the inserted _id field for the mongodb async insertOne function. Can some one help or I have to get rid of the Async driver completely as there is no way ? following this tutoraial http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver-async/getting-started/quick-tour/ ..

Note : The document is successfully inserted to mongodb with the below call but there is no way that I can get the _id from this api.

```
m_messages_collection.insertOne(userMessage, new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "A new message from " + aMessage.m_sender + " inserted to DB" + operation.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you want to get the userMessage._id from the onResult method?

Comment: yes but the api retruns null for result ..  Is there any other way with this async driver ? I tried my best so far and i think there is no way with this library .

Comment: did you check by mongo-shell if the doc have been actually inserted in the collection?

Comment: Answer is Yes .. I am struggling from last one week so I have checked every possible scenario if you want you can also write 2 lines of code and test .. Anyone please if used java mongo async library could only help here through his experience. Now I am planning to use some other library due to no support from community.  I have already vertx in past but writing my project on vertx would eat another one week for me so was trying to see if there is any expert who could help here..

Comment: For all I know, there's no way to get the id as a result to the call. Note however, that also the synchronous driver will not give the _id as a result, as insertOne in synchronous has a void result. So probably your way to go is to create the object id yourself before the call, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723229/how-to-generate-unique-object-id-in-mongodb for a few pointers.