# how to fix duplicate key error collection friends

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, duplicates, mongoose-schema

I get the following error:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.users index: friends.userid_1 dup key: { : null }
```

i dont know how to fix this. in default its nothing, but when i enter new userid with nothing in `friends`, i still get the error. why?

in users schema:

```
   friends : [
        {
            userid : {type: String, default: '', index: { unique: true }},
        }
    ],
    friendRequests: [
        {
            userid : {type: String, default: '', index: { unique: true }},
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You need to generate unique ids for those see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723229/how-to-generate-unique-object-id-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Mongoose official [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays):

> Arrays are special because they implicitly have a default value of [] (empty array).

That's the reason why it implicitly indexes `null` value when you enter nothing in `friends`. To fix that you can explicitly define `default` value for both arrays as `undefined` and create your index as [sparse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) to exclude empty values from `unique` constraint, try:

```
friends : {
    type: [ { userid : {type: String, default: '', index: { unique: true, sparse: true } } } ],
    default: undefined
},
friendRequests: {
    type: [ { userid : {type: String, default: '', index: { unique: true, sparse: true } } } ],
    default: undefined
}
```

EDIT: please make sure that mongoose rebuilds your indexes before testing