# Insert ObjectID in to mongo array elements in Talend tool

Tags: mongodb, talend, objectid

We are migrating the data from Oracle to Mongo DB using Talend tool and we would need to add the object Id to each object inside an array. We have tried to use attribute @type with fixed value as ObjectId but it didn't worked.

We need the output as below:

{

"_id":"12243",

"name": "ABCD",

"city":"XYZ",

"requests":[

{

"_id" : ObjectId("5efdcf15ea9355c419fc9699"), **// How to generate this ObjectId using talend tool in Mongo**

"type":"department",

"value":"Science"

},

{

"_id" : ObjectId("K279kkqasj8ac023878hjc"), **// How to generate this ObjectId using talend tool in Mongo**

"type":"department",

"value":"Commerce"

}

]

}

Comment: Hi, can you explain why you would want to manually add this `_id`, especially inside an "embedded" array? This does not make a lot of sense to me. But maybe you could provide more information to understand.

Comment: Hi,

We want to do data migration using talend tool. Our requirement is to have identity _id value for each of the object inside requests embedded array.

So we would like to insert the **_id** value in Mongo for the same. Could you please advise how we can achieve using talend tool. 

I understand for a main document if we don't assign any **_id** value then mongo by default will assign objectId but in this case we need to have it in **embedded array**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your needs, I assume that manually generating the `ObjectId` should be enough. I will propose to use:

- either the standard MongoDB BSON java library (**recommended**)
- or to generate this element by yourself as soon as you follow the official MongoDB conventions: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid

The recommended way means that you have to add the MongoDB BSON Java library to your Talend project, certainly by including it as a JAR (see links below). I will not explain how (-> out-of-scope). Then simply do the following to add a correct `_id` to your embedded elements:

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
// or
ObjectId id = ObjectId.get();
```

**Related materials:**

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/
- [How to generate unique object id in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723229/how-to-generate-unique-object-id-in-mongodb)
- https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/bson/installation-guide/
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson

Comment: Hello 

Thanks for the response. I have used the logic which you have suggested but i have few issues now.

1. Object Id that is generated is same for all the embedded array elements but it should be different.
2. In the output _id is coming as string but it should have objectId datatype

Now:

It is coming as "_id":"123445324532"

but it should be as 
"_id": ObjectId("1233423")  with type as ObjectId

Comment: What kind of logic are you using for problem (1)? Are you correctly making new ObjectId() for each sub item? What are you Talend input and output shemas like? We will need more info to solve problem (2), as Talend may need to process the ObjectId as String or Object and vice-versa. Also you actually didn't explain why you really need a nested ObjectId in your array.